# Can we get caller's function argument/parameter values using Go

Tags: go, reflection

I already know how to get function name and function location:

```
func Trace(str string) string {
    pc := make([]uintptr, 10)  // at least 1 entry needed
    runtime.Callers(2, pc)
    f := runtime.FuncForPC(pc[0])
    file, line := f.FileLine(pc[0])
    str = Replace(str, "\n", ` `)
    return `-- ` + fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d %s:%s", file, line, f.Name() + str)
}
```

But how to get function argument values? For example, if I call that `Trace` function within:

```
func Test1(a string, b int) {
  Trace(`demo`) 
}
func main() {
  Test1(`aaaa`,123)
}
```

I want to get the value `aaaa` and `123` inside `Trace` function, without have to pass them manually from `Test1` to `Trace` function

Comment: did you find a solution

Comment: yes, just now, here's the hint: https://gist.github.com/tkrajina/880eb4b9a10aee28707e2aa764257503

Comment: how would you get the args that are passed to a method, in your example objects map

Comment: oh, for non object method (a normal function), it's still impossible i think.. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12384

Answer (score -1):

It may be better to use variable arguments. How about that?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "runtime"
)

func main() {
  str := trace(`demo`, 123, "me")
  fmt.Println(str)
}

func trace(str string, args ...interface{}) string {
  pc := make([]uintptr, 10) // at least 1 entry needed
  runtime.Callers(2, pc)
  f := runtime.FuncForPC(pc[0])
  file, line := f.FileLine(pc[0])
  // str = Replace(str, "\n", ` `)
  return `-- ` + fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d %s:%s (%v)", file, line, f.Name(), str, args)
}
```

Comment: hi, i give bad example, what i meant was, getting the caller's argument (Test) from Trace function.